# integration by parts in Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(\mathbb R^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $f,g\in W^{1,1}(\mathbb R^d)$ such that:
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^d}|\nabla f|\,|g|\,<\infty\,,\quad \int_{\mathbb R^d}|f|\,|\nabla g| <\infty \,.$$
Can I say that:
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^d} \nabla\!f\ g \,=\, -\int_{\mathbb R^d} f\;\nabla g \quad?$$
I remember this holds true if $f,g\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^d)$. Can this hypothesis be replaced by my weaker hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not a full answer, since additional assumptions are required.*

The answer is **yes if** we assume also
$$ \int |f\,g| \,<\infty \;.$$

Since both $f,g$ have weak derivative, also $fg$ does and
$$ \nabla(fg) \,=\, \nabla\!f\ g \,+\, f\ \nabla g \;.$$
Moreover $\nabla(fg)\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ thanks to the hypothesis of finite integrals. And $fg\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ by the additonal hypothesis.

Now, for $N\in\mathbb N\,$ let $\phi_N\in C^1_c(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\phi_N(x)=1$ if $|x|\leq N$ and the sequences $\phi_N,\nabla\phi_N$ are uniformly bounded (notice this is possible beacause we are on $\mathbb R^d$). By definition of weak derivative we have:
$$ \int\nabla(fg)\,\phi_N \,=\, - \int fg\,\nabla\phi_N $$
and by dominated convergence as $N\to\infty$ we find:
$$ \int\nabla(fg) = 0 $$
which proves the thesis.

Comment: I think you need to argue that $fg \in L^{1}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$.  Otherwise, it's not obvious what you mean by $\nabla (fg)$.  In your dominated convergence argument, in particular, you seem to be assuming that $fg \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$.  (How do you show $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} fg \nabla \phi_{N} \to 0$?)

Comment: Right, I going to edit

Comment: @PeterMorfe by the way assuming only $fg\in L^1_\textrm{loc}$, since we have $\nabla(fg)\in L^1$, can't we say $fg\in L^1$ by some kind of Poincaré inequality? Or this is false since we are on $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: @tituf: That would work if we knew a-priori that the product $fg$ is a distribution (i.e. $fg\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I'm not sure I see how to guarantee that.